# Склеить изображение и css

Tags: css

Приложение в котором можно редактировать изображения. 
Можно ли сделать чтобы при скачивании картинки обратно сохранялись изменения прикрученные ему с помощью CSS?

Comment: мне кажется такое не возможно возможно не при помощью css

Comment: А если использовать <canvas>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы хотите обрабатывать изображение и потом скачивать это изображение вместе с обработкой? Тогда через canvas или на сервере обрабатывать изображение и возвращать обработанное.

Comment: Спасибо буду через canvas пробовать